# Possible bug in comparison view of edit reviews section

Tags: discussion, bug

I came across the following suggested edit

[image: review]

I noticed that there's an extra `h` hence clicked `improve` option
Which took me to the following screen

[image: edit view]

And there the edit was fine.

Is this a bug? Any idea what's causing the faulty preview..?

Comment: Can you link to the review? Maybe someone else improved it before you could and then it showed you the already improved version or something? c# is also been removed from the title, and various changes to the body.

Answer (score 2):

AS OGHaza already points out, it simply has been edited in the (maybe short) meantime between you looking at the review and clicking the `Improve` button.

Take a look at the revision history: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24426319/revisions: You saw the suggested edit from PiotrWolkowski, but ended up in the already improved version from Michael Walz.

Maybe a hint in this case would be helpful, but that is another issue (and would be a feature request).